# wss process and autocorrelation

Tags: probability, stochastic

In a paper, I saw a quiz question about auto-correlation of a WSS process than I can not understand. It says:

```
Let X(t) be WSS. Which of the following **can be** correct?

 a) E[X(t1) X(t2)] = |t1 - t2|
 b) E[X(t1) X(t2)] = max{t1 - t2,0}
 c) E[X(t1) X(t2)] = max{1- |t1 - t2|,0}
```

The correct answer is c).

Now I don't really understand it. In all three cases, the auto-correlation function depends only on the difference t1 and t2 so they all satisfy this condition.

Thanks in advance